# Can a paper accepted as an extended abstract be submitted to other conferences?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science

Recently, I have a paper only accepted as an extended abstract by a AI conference. Is it still possible to submit this paper to other conferences like KR (International Conference on Principles of Knowledge Representation and Reasoning)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specifics, but often, yes, this is allowed.

In particular, if the paper was accepted in a conference as an extended abstract such that the full paper being submitted to the second conference did not appear in the proceedings in an archival form, it is usually not considered "published" in the formal sense that conferences mean when they refer to original and unpublished work in their calls for submission. This also applies to papers that previously were presented in workshops without archival proceedings.

The idea is that the initial submission as an extended abstract or workshop paper may be a work in progress, with a more complete version submitted for archival to the conference later. But even then, there are usually no formal requirements that new content needs to be added between the two papers, unlike the case where you first submit to a conference and  a full version to a journal later. So even submitting the paper as is should usually be acceptable.

In your particular case, [the submission instructions of KR](https://kr2020.inf.unibz.it/page/submission) (at least the 2020 instance) do explicitly allow this (emphasis mine):

> Both full and short papers must describe original, previously unpublished research, and must not simultaneously be submitted for publication elsewhere. These restrictions do not apply to previously accepted workshop papers with a limited audience and/or **without archival proceedings**, and to papers uploaded at public repositories (e.g., arXiv).

To summarize: usually yes, if the first submission did not appear in the formal proceedings, and no otherwise.

---

Note: if the abstract itself appeared in the proceedings of the first conference, then it should be cited in the second submission. Also, I am assuming your full submission to the second conference is a significantly expanded version of the abstract.

Comment: I worry about "usually yes". I think that in CS the conditions that permit it are rarer than you might think. "Workshop papers" is also significant here.

Comment: @Buffy That's surprising, I am in CS too, and the policies of all the conferences I have seen so far in my subfield (which is close to AI) do not prevent non-archival past work from being submitted. Here, I am assuming that the paper in conference B is significantly extended from the abstract in conference A. My third para was only to cover papers that may have been presented in A but did not appear in its proceedings.

Comment: I agree that if the extended abstract was in the proceedings, and the submission to conference B is very close to it, then there is a problem.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Actually, my extended abstract is not a workshop paper. Is it still possible to submit to KR? Is it belong to the third type, i.e., papers not uploaded at public repositories?

Comment: @Marvin Is your full submission significantly expanded upon the abstract? Did the extended abstract appear in the first conference's proceedings?

Comment: @GoodDeeds The extended abstract is in the first conference's proceedings.  And  full submission is significantly expanded upon the abstract. But the full version is not uploaded at public repositories.

Comment: @Marvin Then it should be fine, looking at the policy linked. Make sure you cite the abstract. If you're still doubtful, contact the second conference's organizers.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess not, unless you take some steps. First, contact the conference organization of the AI conference and pose your question there. And make sure that the organizers of any conference you want to submit to in future know about the abstract. Make it transparent.

Second is that if all of your "innovative" results are present in the extended abstract, then the other conference probably won't be interested, even if they consider it a "separate" work, which they might not.

But if the full paper is sufficiently innovative as an extension of the extended abstract, then you should be fine.

It will take some finesse, quoting and citing the abstract as necessary in the "new" paper.